# How can I return only duplicate rows with a lower identifier

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, duplicates

I have a table with multiple duplicate records. The table has 4 columns e.g. `id`, `post_id`, `post_key` and `post_value`. I am able to return the duplicate entries with the query below.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 ppm
WHERE ppm.post_key = 'some_value'
  AND ppm.post_id IN (SELECT pm.post_id 
                      FROM table1 pm
                      WHERE pm.post_key = 'some_value'
                      GROUP BY pm.post_id 
                      HAVING COUNT(pm.post_id) > 1)
```

It produces an output that looks like:

| id | post_id | post_key | post_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | key1 | value1 |
| 2 | 2 | key1 | value2 |
| 3 | 2 | key1 | value3 |

Since there could be multiple repeating `post_id` e.g. `2`, I'd like to only display the lower `id` values. Using the example above, it would only show the result below since `3` is the larger number than the previous values.

| id | post_id | post_key | post_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | key1 | value1 |
| 2 | 2 | key1 | value2 |

How can I return duplicate rows that have a lower `id`?

The current query returns all duplicate rows. I'd like to only have duplicate rows that have a lower `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-join that checks that the ID is lower in the ON condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id AND t1.id < t2.id
WHERE t1.post_key = 'some_value' AND t2.post_key = 'some_value'
```

I added `DISTINCT` in case there are multiple duplicates, this will only return one of each pair.

Comment: distinct doesn't help, since the ids will be different.  if there are more than two, this will select all but one; you need another left join or where not in to make sure there is no lower id

Comment: That seems to be what they want -- all but the highest. Look at the sample result.

Comment: ah, you are correct, sorry.  and so the distinct is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, post_id, post_key, post_value
FROM (
    select *,
       row_number() over (partition by post_id order by id desc) rn
    from `table1`
) t
WHERE rn <> 1
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/QZf1xFN8